# Furnace running.Shuting off for a few mins then starting again.Continued process

Tags: central-heating

Why would my furnace run it's cycle, shut down and then start up again a few minutes later. Continuing this cycle all night?? Thanks

Comment: How long does it stay on each cycle? What is the thermostat set at? What is the outdoor temperature? How old is your home? Is the home drafty? Does the furnace display any error codes? What is the make and model of the furnace?  Is it exceptionally cold outside in your area?

Answer (score 1):

If the home is maintaining the temperature set on the thermostat (at least AT the thermostat) then it's probable that you are near, but not quite at, "design load" for the furnace. At design load, the furnace runs 100% of the time to keep up with heat loss in the house and maintain temperature - if it gets colder than that outside (below the "design temperature"), the house gets colder than set. At anything less than design load, the furnace runs a fraction of the time, and is off a fraction of the time. The closer the outside temperature is to "design temperature" the longer the run time and shorter the off time. As it gets warmer outside, the off time increases and the run time gets shorter.

Anything that makes the house lose heat faster raises the effective design temperature (doesn't change what temperature was assumed to design it, but alters the actual one.)

Anything that makes the house lose heat slower lowers the  effective design temperature (doesn't change what temperature was assumed to design it, but alters the actual one.)

If the house is NOT maintaining the set temperature AND the furnace is shutting off regularly, something may be in need of maintenance/adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

As Ecnerwal said, your furnace cannot keep up with heating your home. This could be caused by a number of things.

1. Your furnace itself is inadequate and cannot keep up with the load. The rating in BTUs is not high enough.
2. There are inefficiencies in your home which is causing the furnace to work harder than it was designed to.

   - The furnace requires service.
   - Insulation in your home may be inadequate.
   - There could be air leaks and drafts caused by old windows, doors, etc.
   - Too many leaks in the duct work are causing heat loss.
3. You are trying to maintain a temperature that is too high for the furnace to handle.

There are a number of services available that will come into your home and do an energy audit. They will be able to figure out what issues you have in your home. They will do tests like the blower door test to determine how many air leaks you have. They also have special tools such as thermal cameras that can see where the heat loss is. They will also inspect your insulation to see if it meets code. I would also recommend that you have a technician come in and service your heating equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies. The issue was simple. My filters were clogged. First thing I should have looked at. Obviously with the dust build up, not enough cool air was coming in to transfer